# Making sense of the concept of coordinates of a vector with respect to some basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Relevant definition:

> If $B = \{v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$, and $v = a_1v_1, a_2v_2,\ldots, a_nv_n$, then the uniquely defined scalars $a_i$ are called the coordinates of the vector $v$ relative to the
>   basis $B$.

I reworded the example in my book in my own words however awkward, inelegant and ugly they might be. Does what you see below make sense to you?

Let $(x, y, z)$ be a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. Since $xe_1 + ye_2 + ze_3 = (x, y, z)$, we have that $(x, y, z)$ is the coordinate vector of $(x, y, z)$ with respect to the standard basis.

Let $(x, y, z)$ be a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. If $a(2, 1, 1) + b(1, 7, 7) + c(4, -1, 0) = (x, y, z)$, then $(a, b, c) = (z + \frac {7}{13}(x - 6z + 4y, -\frac{1}{13}(x - 6z + 4y), z - y)$ is the coordinate vector of $(x, y, z)$ with respect to the basis $B = \{(2, 1, 1), (1, 7, 7), (4, -1, 0)\}$.

Let $(x, y, z) = (13, 0, 0) \in \mathbb R^3$. Then $(13, 0, 0)$ is a vector. Also, $(13, 0, 0)$ is the coordinate vector of the vector $(13, 0, 0)$ with respect to the standard basis.

Taken as a regular vector, $(13, 0, 0)$ has another coordinate vector $(7, -1, 0)$ with respect to the basis $B$ since $(z + \frac {7}{13}(x - 6z + 4y, -\frac{1}{13}(x - 6z + 4y), z - y) = (7, -1, 0)$.

Comment: I haven't checked the arithmetic but what you've written makes perfect sense, yes.

Comment: @ BrianO. Thank you very much. This concept is super counter-intuitive to me right now.

Comment: Coulda fooled me ;) But I believe you. I think you're approaching it correctly: work through some examples in detail, and you'll build up your intuition. Try an even simpler example, e.g. $\Bbb R^2$, $B=\{(1,1), (-1,1)\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have to pay 17 dollars in cash, and money is available in 10 dollar and 1 dollar notes (bills). Then we can give it out using 1 ten-dollar and  seven 1-dollar bils. (1,7) are the co-ordinates. Instead if you are using five-dollar and two-dollar units (differnet 'basis') then you can pay that as 3 five-dollar bills plus 2 one dollar bills, So (3,2) is the co-ordinates for the same amount of 17 dollars.

My analogy is not perfect as basis means only one way  that amount should be possible (e.g. one can use 1  five-dollar bills and 12  one-dollar bills).
But this should cure you from the counter-intuitive feeling you are getting.